# Add a new folder when uploading files using php

Tags: php

I want to automatically create a folder, using the users email address, if one does not already exists. This action should occur when they upload a file.

SOLVED. I updated this code for anyone who might need it. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST["checkFile"]) && $_FILES["selectFile"]["name"] != "") {
            $target_path_pdf = "uploads/pdfs/$email/";

            if ( ! is_dir($target_path_pdf)) {
                mkdir($target_path_pdf);
            }

            $target_path_pdf = $target_path_pdf . str_replace(' ', '_', basename($_FILES["selectFile"]["name"]));
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["selectFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path_pdf)) {
            }
            else {
                $flag = 1;
            }
            $pdfcaption = $_POST['pdfCaption1'];
        }

        if(isset($_POST["checkPicture"]) && $_FILES["selectPicture"]["name"] != "") {
            $target_path_pic = "uploads/pictures/$email/";

            if ( ! is_dir($target_path_pic)) {
                mkdir($target_path_pic);
            }


            $target_path_pic = $target_path_pic . str_replace(' ', '_', basename($_FILES["selectPicture"]["name"]));
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["selectPicture"]["tmp_name"], $target_path_pic)) {
            }
            else {
                $flag = 1;
            }
            $piccaption = $_POST['picCaption1'];
        }
```

Comment: so why don't you make the folder?

Comment: I can't add a folder for every user. That wouldn't be an efficient system. The system should add a new folder for the user if they don't already have one.

Comment: So make a new folder when you need it. It really is that simple.

Comment: So when people upload pictures to facebook, Zuck sits in a room somewhere creating folders for all the users?? I dont think so...

Comment: You do know PHP can make folders, right?

Comment: Yea and the code above is my attempt at using php to create a folder(more specifically a directory) to store a users files....but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be super secure, but that's a different problem.

For the first part:

```
$target_path_pdf = "uploads/pdfs/$email/";

if(!is_dir($target_path_pdf)){
    mkdir($target_path_pdf);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

**EDIT**

Even though it might be obvious it can't hurt to explain.
The script simply checks if the directory already exists, and if it doesn't it creates one.